# any difference between "virtual void IBase::Foo" and "virtual void Foo"?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've used VisualAssistX `Implement Virtual Methods` option and it generated:

```
class Base: public IBase
{
public:
    Base(void);
    ~Base(void);
    virtual void IBase::Foo();
```

I've noticed that I can omit `IBase` and program still compiles like that:

```
    virtual void Foo();
```

If this is the same code? Why VisualAssistX inserts `IBase::`? Is it just kind of "code-style" to improve readability?

Thanks

Comment: I think inserting the namespace/class name *inside* a class declaration **decreases** readability. The bare function name is just fine.

Comment: Is this even valid C++?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I can't get this to compile using `g++ 4.7.2`: `error: cannot declare member function 'B1::foo' within 'D'`

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Good catch, although I would seriously punish Stroustrup for having added multiple inheritance support to C++.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925792/distinct-implementations-for-pure-virtual-functions-with-same-name

Comment: @NPE it isn't *standard* C++, but it is MSVC C++, which, as we all know, doesn't conform to any standards but it's own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would help resolve the ambiguity if you were to derive from multiple base classes with clashing virtual functions. I suspect this is the reason why VisualAssistX is choosing to insert the `IBase::`.

Whether `IBase::` helps improve readability is debatable. I personally find it distracting.

Furthermore, the syntax is not even standard C++. See [Distinct implementations for pure virtual functions with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925792/distinct-implementations-for-pure-virtual-functions-with-same-name) for a discussion and for a suggestion how the multiple inheritance problem can be solved using standard, portable C++.

Comment: It is, however MSVC-C++, which is probably only what's relevant to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not improving readability, the other way around. The scope prefix is for use from outside or when there can be resolution ambiguity, using the prefix inside the scope itself just obfuscates the code and actually contradicts OOP principles. When inside scope your entity doesn't need to indicate it again, it's completely redundant. Regarding the VA I can only speculate that it was simpler for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the first is not valid C++.

Perhaps your compiler accepts it (since that compiler has many strange "extensions" to the language); but if you need your code to be portable to more standard compilers, then you will need to use the second form.

> Why VisualAssistX inserts `IBase::`?

I would guess that it's a misguided attempt to indicate that the function overrides the one declared in `IBase`; but I've no idea why anyone thought that might be a good idea.

> Is it just kind of "code-style" to improve readability?

On the contrary; this bogus declaration makes the function look like a member of `IBase`, when it's actually a member of `Base`. That kind of confusion is going to reduce readability.