# C++ How to multiple inherits from interfaces with different return types?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, multiple-inheritance

Perhaps i have two interfaces with same function names and parameters, but with different return values:

```
struct A { virtual void foo() = 0; };
struct B { virtual int foo() = 0; };
```

How to define class C, that inherits this interfaces (if it's of course possible)?
For example i write some pseudocode that doesn't compiled:

```
// this code is fake, it doesn't compiled!!
struct C : A, B
{
    // how to tell compiler what method using if referenced from C?
    using void foo();  // incorrect in VS 2012
    // and override A::foo() and B::foo()?
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "void C::foo();\n"; } // incorrect
    virtual int foo() { std::cout << "int C::foo();\n"; return 0; } // incorrect
 }
 // ... for use in code
 C c;
 A &a = c;
 B &b = c;
 c.foo();     // call void C::foo() when reference from C instance
 a.foo();     // call void C::foo() when reference from A instance
 b.foo();     // call int C::foo() when reference from B instance
```

Comment: Why would you want something like this?

Comment: maybe he doesnt own A and B; but has to make C that implements both. Seems a reasonable question

Comment: That's not possible in C++ (not as you coded it). Functions are identified by their parameter types, not by their return types.

Comment: FYI - C# lets you say A:foo , B:foo in this case (explicit implementation)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004820/inherit-interfaces-which-share-a-method-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, but not because of the multiple inheritance. Ambiguity arises due to invalid overload of `foo` in class `C`. You can't have both `int foo()` and `void foo()` since return type is not part of function signature, thus the compiler won't be able to resolve the calls to `foo`. You can look at your interface as a union of both `A` and `B` classes, so logically the problem is already present before the actual inheritance. Since from compiler perspective `A` and `B` are 2 distinct and unrelated types, there is no problem while compiling them and the error is delayed until point of actual unification in class `C`.

See more here about function signatures and overloading: [Is the return type part of the function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature)

Answer (score 2):

What you *can* do is to put all the shared stuff into a `virtual` base, say `C_base` and override the conflicting `virtual` functions in auxiliary classes, each. Since the shared stuff for `C` is readily available in `C_base` is essentially like in a the most derived `C`. Finally, you `C` class just because the class pulling things together:

```
struct A { virtual void foo() = 0; };
struct B { virtual int foo() = 0; };

struct C_base { int all_data; };

struct A_aux: virtual C_base, A {
    void foo() { std::cout << "A_aux::foo()\n"; }
};

struct B_aux: virtual C_base, B {
    int foo() { std::cout << "B_aux::foo()\n"; return 0; }
};

struct C : A_aux, B_aux
{
    using A_aux::foo;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly qualify.

```
class C : A, B {
public:
    void A::foo() { ... }
    int B::foo() { ... }
};
```

Edit:

This appears to be an MSVC extension, rather than Standard.

Comment: I thought so, too, but trying to compile it failed for me. I haven't found the correct syntax, yet...

Comment: I found the reason. I think it's an MSVC extension. It seems odd that the Standard would not cover this case (and doubly odd that an MSVC extension would actually be patching a hole instead of causing several :P).

Comment: Good stuff. Any way besides casting to invoke them via instance of `C` class?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to overwrite a virtual function's return type using the same signature (as @icepack's answer explains).

An alternate approach might be having a template base class declaring `foo()` with a return type specified as template parameter, and providing specializations for concrete return parameter types.

This would be a generalization of @Dietmar Kühl's proposal.